# Need help in finding integral value of $\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} dx \int_{-1}^{1} dy\ \delta(\sin2x)\ \delta(x-y)$?

Tags: dirac-delta

I am trying to find value of the following integral:

$\int_{\frac{-\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} dx \int_{-1}^{1} dy\ \delta(\sin2x)\ \delta(x-y)$

I have some experience in solving integrals that contain Dirac delta function in one variable, but here it is in two variable. I am completely clueless and don't even know how to approach this problem. I am not expecting the solution, need someone to guide me what approach will help me to evaluate this integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend change-of-variables manipulations to the Dirac delta, the following composition is defined:
$$\delta(\mathbf f(\mathbf x))=\sum_{\mathbf r_i}\frac{\delta(\mathbf x-\mathbf r_i)}{|\mathbf J_{\mathbf f}(\mathbf r_i)|}$$
where $\mathbf r_i$ are the roots of $\mathbf f$. For the given $\mathbf f(x,y)=(\sin2x,x-y)$, there is only one root in the domain of integration, $(0,0)$, and
$$|\mathbf J_{\mathbf f}|=\begin{vmatrix}2\cos2x&1\\0&-1\end{vmatrix}=-2\cos2x$$
Evaluating this at $(0,0)$ and taking the absolute value gives 2, so (within the domain of integration)
$$\delta(\mathbf f(\mathbf x))=\frac{\delta(\mathbf x-(0,0))}2$$
Thus the integral over the domain is $\frac12$.

Comment: Thanks, @Parcly. I am afraid the book gives the answer as $\frac{1}{2}$. I am confused! Could you please elaborate? I am not able to follow. Apologies for naive understanding of calculus.

Comment: @orion OK, fixed.